# Laravel query idea

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm a bit stuck writing something that should be pretty simple, so I need your help. I have one main table "posts", and two other related tables "categories" and "sectors".

I'm making the filter route, and the logic should be to return all posts, except those that contain sector X along with category Y. Can I write it in one query, or do I need to retrieve all posts, and then later remove those with some array mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to write it myself so in case someone stumbles upon the same problem, this is the solution. So to not include a post in the results, it's required for the post to have both sector and category. If either one is missing, or neither, the post should be included in the results normally.

This is the part of the code that should be added to the query:

```
Post::query()->where(function($q){
                        $q->where(function ($mainQ) {
                            $mainQ->whereDoesntHave('sections', function (Builder $subQ) {
                                $subQ->where('type', 'X');
                            })->orWhere(function ($mainQ) {
                                $mainQ->whereDoesntHave('taxonomies', function (Builder $subQ) {
                                    $subQ->where('type', 'category')->where('name', 'Y');
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `whereDoesntHave()` queries. Assuming you pass category & sector as query params (single ID in this case), and that you have `category()` and `sector()` relations on your models, you can do something like this:

```
$query = Post::query();

$query->when($request->input('category'), function ($q) use ($request) {
    return $q->whereDoesntHave('category', function ($category){
        return $category->where('id', $request->input('category'));
    });
});

$query->when($request->input('sector'), function ($q) use ($request) {
    return $q->whereDoesntHave('sector', function ($sector){
        return $sector->where('id', $request->input('sector'));
    });
});
```

The [when()](https://laraveldaily.com/post/less-know-way-conditional-queries) function just replaces the if-else statement, so you don't have to check if your params are passed to the request

If your query params contain more than one category or sector value, just change the last query to:

```
return $category->whereIn('id', $request->input('category')); //$request->input('category') has to be array


return $sector->whereIn('id', $request->input('sector')); //$request->input('sector') has to be array
```

Comment: The problem with your queries is that if either category or sector is present, the item will be removed from the results. That's not what I need. The result should be removed ONLY if both sector X and category Y are present on the post

Comment: You're right. Didn't realize it from your original question. I would suggest the same thing that you wrote down below.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have corresponding Eloquent Models "Post", "Category" and "Sector" which have also relations defined between themselves. It is then very easy to query for related models in or not in a relation as described in https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: It may sound easy, but I can't get to it. It would be easy the other way around if I only wanted to get posts that contain certain sectors and categories. But in my example, I have really complicated query already, and I need to add the part that would "remove" posts from the query results that contain sector X and category Y. So, all other posts should be returned except for those that contains those two relations.